# looping through same multiple nodes in an xml and merging numbers that are strings

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, xml-parsing

I am having an issue where i am looping through multiple of the same nodes in an xml bill. As i was looping through the values and merging them accordingly I didnt realize that the datatype was a string. I need some help merging/summing up numbers that are strings. the loop contains all of the values included in the node but i am only showing the portion i need help with.

```
    private static ServiceAddressBillDetail GetServiceAccountUsageAndBillingDetail(string requestSA, string xmlBill, XmlNodeList detailPageNodes)
    {
        var saBillDetail = new ServiceAddressBillDetail();
        saBillDetail.UsageServiceName = requestSA;

        foreach (XmlNode detailPageNode in detailPageNodes)
        {

            if (totalSvcUseXMLNodes.Count > 0 && totalSvcUseXMLNodes[0].HasChildNodes)
            {

                var totalSvcNode = totalSvcUseXMLNodes[0].SelectSingleNode("IRBILGP_SA_TOTAL_KWH.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_STATEMENT");
                if (totalSvcNode == null)
                {
                    totalSvcNode = totalSvcUseXMLNodes[0].SelectSingleNode("IRBILGU_US_KWH_USAGE.USAGE");
                }
                saBillDetail.TotalServiceUsage = totalSvcNode.InnerText;                 
            }
        }
    }
```

This is how i had it and i figured the datatype was a string. this way just concatenates the values together.

```
    private static ServiceAddressBillDetail GetServiceAccountUsageAndBillingDetail(string requestSA, string xmlBill, XmlNodeList detailPageNodes)
    {
        var saBillDetail = new ServiceAddressBillDetail();
        saBillDetail.UsageServiceName = requestSA;

        foreach (XmlNode detailPageNode in detailPageNodes)
        {

            if (totalSvcUseXMLNodes.Count > 0 && totalSvcUseXMLNodes[0].HasChildNodes)
            {

                var totalSvcNode = totalSvcUseXMLNodes[0].SelectSingleNode("IRBILGP_SA_TOTAL_KWH.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_STATEMENT");
                if (totalSvcNode == null)
                {
                    totalSvcNode = totalSvcUseXMLNodes[0].SelectSingleNode("IRBILGU_US_KWH_USAGE.USAGE");
                }
                saBillDetail.TotalServiceUsage += totalSvcNode.InnerText;                 
            }
        }
    }
```

then i tried something like this where i am using int.Parse and adding the result back to result. But i am getting an error with the second result in the `result = result + int.Parse(totalSvcNode.InnerText);` saying it is unassigned variable

```
    private static ServiceAddressBillDetail GetServiceAccountUsageAndBillingDetail(string requestSA, string xmlBill, XmlNodeList detailPageNodes)
    {
        var saBillDetail = new ServiceAddressBillDetail();
        saBillDetail.UsageServiceName = requestSA;

        foreach (XmlNode detailPageNode in detailPageNodes)
        {

            if (totalSvcUseXMLNodes.Count > 0 && totalSvcUseXMLNodes[0].HasChildNodes)
            {

                var totalSvcNode = totalSvcUseXMLNodes[0].SelectSingleNode("IRBILGP_SA_TOTAL_KWH.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_STATEMENT");
                if (totalSvcNode == null)
                {
                    totalSvcNode = totalSvcUseXMLNodes[0].SelectSingleNode("IRBILGU_US_KWH_USAGE.USAGE");
                }
                int result;


                //saBillDetail.TotalServiceUsage += totalSvcNode.InnerText;
                result = result + int.Parse(totalSvcNode.InnerText);

                saBillDetail.TotalServiceUsage = result.ToString();
            }

        }

    }
```

I am stuck with the logic since its not two different TotalServiceUsage i am adding up together. Its the same TotalServiceUsage added up for every node found. I am a pretty new programmer and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your last example int result needs to be initialized outside the for loop:

```
int result =0;
```

If TotalServiceUsage is an int you can just use:

```
saBillDetail.TotalServiceUsage += int.Parse(totalSvcNode.InnerText);
```

Comment: TotalServiceUsage is a string, thats my issue @Neal

Comment: Did you try putting int result = 0; just before the foreach loop?

Comment: You can't have result = result + whatever, without result first being initialized with a value.